# Remove class in nav_menu_link_attibutes filter

Tags: php, menus

I have the following code in the functions.php file of my child theme:

```
function add_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if ( $class_key = array_search( 'search-class', $item->classes ) !== FALSE ) {
        $atts['data-something'] = 'something';
        $atts['class'] = 'something-class';
        //the following line is the one relevant to this question
        unset($item->classes[$class_key]);
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
```

After using the class `search-class` to locate the item, I would like to remove it from the item. However, my call to `unset($item->classes[$class_key]);` doesn't work.

I don't exactly understand what object `$item` is and this is probably the problem. When I call `get_class()` on `$item` I get `WP_Post`, but `WP_Post` does not have a `classes` property. So how is `$item->classes` returning an array of classes?

(I'm new to PHP and WordPress)

Can I remove `search-class` class from the array of classes in the `$item` object within my method?

Comment: if you are new at PHP, the first thing to learn is to look in the variables to see what is inside. this can done with functions http://php.net/print_r and http://php.net/var_dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first look at this part:

> I don't exactly understand what object `$item` is and this is probably
>   the problem. When I call `get_class()` on `$item` I get `WP_Post`, but
>   `WP_Post` does not have a classes property. So how is `$item->classes`
>   returning an array of classes?

Few notes regarding the structure of menus in WordPress:

- Each navigational menu is registered as a term in the `nav_menu` taxonomy.
- Then when we add items to that menu, we are creating new post objects of the type `nav_menu_item`.
- The tree structure for each menu is not the stored in the `post_parent` field of the `nav_menu_item` posts, as expected. We actually find it in the post meta table where it's stored under the `_menu_item_menu_item_parent` meta key, for each `nav_menu_item` post.
- The `$item` menu item data object is a decorated `WP_Post` object, i.e. with extra attributes added with the [`wp_setup_nav_menu_item()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) function:

  ```
  /**
   * Decorates a menu item object with the shared navigation menu item properties.
   *
   * Properties:
   * - ID:               The term_id if the menu item represents a taxonomy term. 
   * - attr_title:       The title attribute of the link element for this menu item.
   * - classes:          The array of class attribute values for the link element of this menu item.
   * - db_id:            The DB ID of this item as a nav_menu_item object, if it exists (0 if it doesn't exist).
   * - description:      The description of this menu item.
   * - menu_item_parent: The DB ID of the nav_menu_item that is this item's menu parent, if any. 0 otherwise.
   * - object:           The type of object originally represented, such as "category," "post", or "attachment."
   * - object_id:        The DB ID of the original object this menu item represents, e.g. ID for posts and term_id for categories.
   * - post_parent:      The DB ID of the original object's parent object, if any (0 otherwise).
   * - post_title:       A "no title" label if menu item represents a post that lacks a title.
   * - target:           The target attribute of the link element for this menu item.
   * - title:            The title of this menu item.
   * - type:             The family of objects originally represented, such as "post_type" or "taxonomy."
   * - type_label:       The singular label used to describe this type of menu item.
   * - url:              The URL to which this menu item points.
   * - xfn:              The XFN relationship expressed in the link of this menu item.
   * - _invalid:         Whether the menu item represents an object that no longer exists.
  ```

Then let's look at this part:

> After using the class `search-class` to locate the item, I would like to
>   remove it from the item. However, my call to
>   `unset($item->classes[$class_key]);` doesn't work.

It's too late to remove classes from the `$item` object, within the `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter, in order to remove classes from the menu items (li tags).

We can e.g. use the `nav_menu_css_class` filter to modify these classes.

*It's also probably a better approach in general to use such a filter rather than modifying the data object directly, because other plugins might depend on the raw data object.*

Here's an example how to remove the `search-class` class:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', function( $classes, $item, $args, $depth )
{
    return array_filter(
        (array) $classes, 
        function( $val ) { return 'search-class' !== $val; } 
    ); 

}, 10, 4 );
```

Then we can use the `nav_menu_link_attributes`filter  to add a data attribute and append a class to the anchor tag:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item, $args )
{
    // Nothing to do
    if( 
           ! isset( $item->classes ) 
        || ! in_array( 'klasi1', $item->classes, true ) 
        || ! isset( $atts['class'] ) 
    )
        return $atts;

    // Add data attribute to anchor tag
    $atts['data-something'] = 'something';

    // Append an anchor class
    $classes = explode( ' ', $atts['class'] );
    $classes[] = 'something-class';
    $atts['class'] = join( ' ', array_filter( $classes ) );

    return $atts;
}, 10, 3 );
```

We might also want to restrict the above filters to a given menu, by checking if `$args->theme_location` is `'primary'` or `$args->menu->slug` is `'somemenuslug'`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will look over my code, refresh my memory and let you know. Thank you.